# convert pdf to image : angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am showing some list of pdf's in my angular application. I am getting the pdf URL's from my backend. Is there any way to convert the first page of the pdf to image.

I have tried to display the pdf's in a iframe. But there is a wired scrollbar showing in the iframe. So i was thinking if there is any way to convert the pdf's first page to image?

My Current HTML -

```
<div class="mags-list">
  <ul>
     <li class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let mag of mags">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <iframe [attr.src]="mag.file_url | safe : 'resourceUrl'" frameborder="0" width="266" height="345"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
       </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be better to use a npm package to convert a pdf to images and grab the first page or implementing in on the API call to get the pdfs

Comment: @Passersby, can you suggest any package?

Comment: From a google search, I found these, I have never used them before:

https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-jpg
https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-jpg

Comment: Another easy trick you can do is ```window.open``` the image in new  tab and ```window.print``` to save as pdf. But I would suggest using any npm package than this method. This method allows you to have no dependencies.